# Failed to find provider info for android.server.provider.checkin error

Tags: android, xml

I keep getting this exception in LogCat

Failed to find provider info for android.server.provider.checkin

The android dev reference seems to have no info on this at all, I have however seen some vague reference's to a provider tag and an authorities attribute relating to a getType method???

I have a getBytes() method but that is all. Anyway, I added one to the manifest like so:

**android:enabled="true">**

Eclipse complains about this, says its looking for missing required attribute name, what required attribute name, Android's dev reference does not say. Does anyone have an example of how thing is supposed to be setup. I ma not sure if I am even on the right track here...

Thanks
Rick

Comment: I didn't quite get from your explanation whether the problem is in the manifest or in the code, but are you missing an end tag, e.g. android:enabled="true"/> ?

Comment: Sorry about that this is what I should have put from the manifest.xml file
<provider 
         android:authorities="java.lang.String.getBytes"   
         android:enabled="true"
        
         >
         </provider>

Answer (score 1):

make sure your <provider> tag is inside of your <application> tag.  that's been biting me just now.